# WebAPI routeTemplate customization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to change the routeTemplate format of WebAPI.

Currently the default is set to be `api/{controller}/{id}`

I want to know if its possible to change the "api" part to say something else so the format would be something like

`myapi/{controller}/{id}`

I changed it in the global.asax.cs file but when I build the project, in order to load the service it still requires me to browse to `/api/` instead of what I put in its place.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using RTM version of MVC 4?

The reason why I am asking is that in RTM the HTTP route is in App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs, and, yes, changing the route from "api" to "myapi" here should work.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I did not realize the route was registered in this file.  I had added it to the Global.asax based on a tutorial which apparently is outdated.  So the method I have been working on apparently doesn't actually do anything and the proper place to configure the route is in the App_Start config file.  Thank you very much, it works just as I would have expected.